# Number of sessions containing a pair of pages - using matrix indexes as pairs

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

I have this dataframe

```
lf = structure(list(session_id = c(48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 54L, 
54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 
74L, 74L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 90L, 90L, 90L), userId = c(48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 89, 89, 89), datetime = structure(c(1457050110, 
1457050111, 1457050112, 1457050114, 1457050117, 1457050118, 1457052045, 
1457052048, 1457052050, 1457052051, 1457052052, 1457052054, 1457057067, 
1457057067, 1457057067, 1457057070, 1457057071, 1457058143, 1457058143, 
1457058144, 1457058149, 1457058150, 1457059193, 1457059193, 1457059195, 
1457059198, 1457059199, 1457063485, 1457063486, 1457063486), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), referer = c(35, 18, 14, 20, 9, 20, 
35, 9, 16, 47, 48, 24, 35, 6, 56, 8, 16, 22, 10, 6, 9, 57, 21, 
6, 60, 61, 8, 22, 64, 65), request = c(7, 7, 14, 20, 9, 4, 9, 
1, 12, 20, 6, 12, 4, 15, 8, 8, 12, 10, 6, 6, 13, 1, 5, 6, 20, 
1, 8, 3, 6, 13)), .Names = c("session_id", "userId", "datetime", 
"referer", "request"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

Looks like this:

```
  session_id userId            datetime referer request
1          48     48 2016-03-04 00:08:30      35       7
2          48     48 2016-03-04 00:08:31      18       7
3          48     48 2016-03-04 00:08:32      14      14
4          48     48 2016-03-04 00:08:34      20      20
5          48     48 2016-03-04 00:08:37       9       9
6          48     48 2016-03-04 00:08:38      20       4
7          54     53 2016-03-04 00:40:45      35       9
8          54     53 2016-03-04 00:40:48       9       1
9          54     53 2016-03-04 00:40:50      16      12
10         54     53 2016-03-04 00:40:51      47      20
11         54     53 2016-03-04 00:40:52      48       6
12         54     53 2016-03-04 00:40:54      24      12
13         72     71 2016-03-04 02:04:27      35       4
14         72     71 2016-03-04 02:04:27       6      15
15         72     71 2016-03-04 02:04:27      56       8
16         72     71 2016-03-04 02:04:30       8       8
17         72     71 2016-03-04 02:04:31      16      12
18         74     73 2016-03-04 02:22:23      22      10
19         74     73 2016-03-04 02:22:23      10       6
20         74     73 2016-03-04 02:22:24       6       6
21         74     73 2016-03-04 02:22:29       9      13
22         74     73 2016-03-04 02:22:30      57       1
23         78     77 2016-03-04 02:39:53      21       5
24         78     77 2016-03-04 02:39:53       6       6
25         78     77 2016-03-04 02:39:55      60      20
26         78     77 2016-03-04 02:39:58      61       1
27         78     77 2016-03-04 02:39:59       8       8
28         90     89 2016-03-04 03:51:25      22       3
29         90     89 2016-03-04 03:51:26      64       6
30         90     89 2016-03-04 03:51:26      65      13
```

Now I am creating a matrix with this piece of code

```
k <- length(unique(lf$request))
M <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = k, ncol = k)

for (i in 1:k) {
  for (j in 1:k) {
    M[i, j] <- weight(i, j)  # i want to write my function here 
  }
}
```

where `weight(i,j)` is a function whose usage is the following ;
`weight(i,j) = Number` of sessions containing both pages `i` and `j` / max(number of sessions containing page `i`, number of sessions containing pages  `j`)

**Edit1 :** What i am trying to do is check for each pair of page correspond to request column in dataframe. If particular pair of pages present in a session we return true and later do the sum to count number of session containing those pages ...thats the idea.

**Edit2 :** Ok trying to explain it further. In given dataframe request column is our pages(page Ids) so we have to check against this column for pages pair.
Suppose we're looping at instance M[2,3] meaning we have to look for page pair(2,3) .If those pages/requests(Ids) present in a session(using group_by) we return true and sum those(meaning Finding out no. of sessions containg both pages) ...we'll do the same for individual pages(i.e. page 2 and page 3).
Function will return numbers not a dataframe .

Comment: The `dput` output is giving errors `Error in structure(list(session_id = c(48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 54L,  : 
  object 'session_id' not found`

Comment: excuse me, what  do you need exactly? I sincerely don't understand! :(

Comment: We can't read your file that was produced with dput, the code returns an error Error in structure(list(session_id = c(48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 54L,  : 
  object 'session_id' not found

Comment: please create a sample output; the verbose output description refers to pages but there is no column name that contains pages

Comment: `dput` doesn't work on dplyr's `grouped_df` objects. `dput(as.data.frame(lf))` will work fine, or you can just remove the extra stuff (done in edits).

Comment: Can you be more explicit in your example? Using your sample input, if we look at `M[2, 3]` then the 2 and 3 are the 2nd and 3rd unique `request` numbers, which you refer to as "page id", so we're talking about `request` 14 and `request` 20. They are only both present in one `session_id`, 48, so we return 1. Is this right? And then, later, we'd divide by the max of the number of `session_id`s that have `request` 14 or that have request 20? Is that right? And why do you include `userId`, `datetime`, and `referrer`? If they're irrelevant, remove them from the question.

Comment: no they're not 14 and 20 request. we look for those requests 2 and 3 in each session and if those requests are present in that session we return true . Here i am proving a sample code which checks for request=6 in each session lf %>% group_by(session_id) %>% summarise(do_match = 6 %in% request)

Comment: and i am using function  sum on that to count number of sessions containing requestid=6 but getting error.If i save it in another dataframe then sum working .How to apply sum in chaining way dplyr in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this approach :-

```
#number of sessions containing a pair of pages
Nab = function(tf,i,j){
  chal = tf %>% group_by(session_id) %>% do(do_match = c(i,j) %in% .$request)
  chal1 = lapply(chal$do_match,sum)==2
  chal2 = sum(chal1)

  chal3 = lapply(chal$do_match,function(x)sum(x[][1]))
  chal4 = sum(unlist(chal3))

  chal5 = lapply(chal$do_match,function(x)sum(x[][2]))
  chal6 = sum(unlist(chal5))
  my = list("Nab"= chal2,"Na"= chal4,"Nb"= chal6)
  return (my)
}

#Creating Matrix and calculating TC and FC
k=length(unique(tf$request))
FC = matrix(data=NA, nrow=k, ncol=k)

for(i in 1:k){
  for(j in 1:k){
    fc = Nab(tf,i,j)
    Nab1 = fc$Nab
    Na1 = fc$Na
    Nb1 = fc$Nb
    FC[i,j] = Nab1/max(Na1,Nb1)

  }
}
```

But as it contains loop ....its slow .Looking for more decent answer on this.Thanks!